# Programmatically adding fields to specific vocabularies

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Is it possible to add fields to vocabulary terms programmatically in a custom module?

I know it can be done at admin/structure/taxonomy/news_client_sites/fields in the UI, but I'd like to add the fields during the module install process.

I have specific vocabularies I've created during hook_install, but I'd like to be able to add fields to them as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that with taxonomies, vocabularies are bundles of taxonomy_term entities.

So, it turned out to be something like this:

Assuming a taxonomy machine name of example_taxonomy

```
  $field_example = array(
    'field_name' => 'field_example',
    'cardinality' => 1,
    'type' => 'text',
  );
  field_create_field($field_example);

  $field_example_instance = array(
    'field_name' => 'field_example',
    'label' => st('Example Text Field'),
    'bundle' => 'example_taxonomy',
    'entity_type' => 'taxonomy_term',
    'widget' => array(
      'type' => 'text_textfield',
    ),
  );
  field_create_instance($field_example_instance);
```

So, yeah, it turns out that taxonomy_terms are the entities and vocabularies are the bundles...